# What is the best way to store the state of NSTreeController contents in Swift?

Tags: swift, core-data, nsoutlineview, nscoding, nstreecontroller

I've built the custom `NSOutlineView` with `NSTreeController`, and I faced with the huge complexity of saving its state. Usage of `Core Data` is too tedious since I have implemented drag and drop support as well.

So my question is more general. What is the best way to save `NSTreeController`'s state? Is it achievable with `NSCoding`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "custom NSOutlineView" and "state"? Do you want to use `autosaveExpandedItems`? What is the class of the tree controller?

Comment: @Willeke, I meant the custom design for it and icons.

Comment: @Willeke, I have the next class : `class MainCatalogController: NSViewController, NSOutlineViewDelegate, NSOutlineViewDataSource {}`, and `@IBOutlet var treeController: NSTreeController!` inside it.


I want to implement saving to multiple storage types as locally, using Core Data, and iCloud syncing. So I am looking for the best way how to save the tree's state. E.g. I did drag and drop, or created a new folder, and closed the app. And next time when I'll open the app there should be exactly the same folders structure.

Comment: @Willeke, I am trying to achieve the same catalog behavior as Apple Notes app.